# Chaining together AsyncTasks in Android - better to use Threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a series of network operations that must be done sequentially:

1. Connect to a specific Wifi Device's AP
2. Send it some data over TCP
3. Connect to a different AP
4. Send UDP broadcast

I currently have it implemented by starting each `AsynchTask` in the `onPostExecute` of the previous `AsynchTask`. Now I realize that in a different part of the app I would like to reuse the code `AsynchTask 2` (to send different data), however I can't because I do not want `AsynchTask 3` to start when it is finished. I realize that I could use a flag (a boolean or int) and pass it to the `AsynchTask 2` and not start `AsynchTask 3` if the flag is false, but this seems confusing and messy.

Can this be done in a cleaner way using Threads? Or would I end up using essentially the same logic i.e. using a flag in a `run()` method?

Let me know if you would like me to post the code, however it is fairly long and I feel that my question is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you're going to be running all of these tasks in sequence, why not put them all in the same `AsyncTask`? You can still use different classes or functions to make your code more compartmentalized.

Comment: Ok if I put the code regarding sending data over tcp in a separate method within one large AsyncTask how would I call that as its own AsyncTask from a different class?

Comment: Why do you need it as its own `AsyncTask`? Can't you just call `method1()`, `method2()`, `method3()`, `method4()`, in `onPostExecute()` from the same task instance? Your `AsyncTask` can then take in a custom POJO parameter, which you use to conditionally call the four methods.

Comment: Yep that could be done, is there any difference between the custom POJO parameter you mentioned and the flag I mentioned in the post i.e. essentially just doing a switch on an int passed in? (That is kind of what I wanted to avoid)

Comment: Not really, but it allows for better design in case you need to also add conditional parameters. You could also use a `Bundle` if you're feeling lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `ArrayList` that would hold a list of the `AsyncTask`s to perform, then start the first one.

In each `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute`, send a message back to a `Handler` or a `BroadcastReceiver`, which will then start the next `AsyncTask` from the `ArrayList`, which would likely either be in a `Singleton` or it would be static. I'd give code for it, but I just don't have the time right now.

Also, using `Thread`s might be able to make it cleaner, but it could also make it much messier, all depending on how you implement it. I personally never use `AsyncTask`. I always use `Thread` and `Handler`, but that's just preference.

Comment: Ok and then in a class where I don't want to chain the tasks I could just call an individual one without a handler (and do nothing with the response)? Or just have a different handler which would not start the next task?